# Why is env variable token not being parsed properly by mapbox-gl-js?

Tags: next.js, mapbox-gl-js

Building in latest version of Next. Have installed mapbox-gl-js.
Created a .env file with:

```
MapboxAccessToken=my_special_token
```

I have a map.js component with basic template that pulls in that variable with the following:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactMapGL from 'react-map-gl';


const MapView = () => {
    const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        latitude: 37.7577,
        longitude: -122.4376,
        zoom: 8
    });
    console.log(process.env.MapboxAccessToken)
    return ( 
        <div>
            <ReactMapGL {...viewport} mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.MapboxAccessToken} />
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default MapView;
```

The console log shows the actual token so I know its pulling it in.

However, this produces no map and an error, "A valid API token is required to use Mapbox data."

```
<ReactMapGL {...viewport} mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.MapboxAccessToken} />
```

But when I put the token in as a string such as below, the map generates.

```
<ReactMapGL {...viewport} mapboxApiAccessToken="my_special_token" />
```

I restarted dev server of course and other env variables work just fine. Not sure if Mapbox is looking for something unique, but their docs don't recognize this issue.

Anyone have an idea as to why the env variable being passed doesn't work but the literal string does?

Comment: "_The console log shows the actual token so I know its pulling it in_": Where are you looking the logs? On the terminal or in the dev-tools? Most probably you are checking it on the terminal, and your browser is not receiving the token as you haven't prefixed it with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`. Refer: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser

Comment: @brc-dd - ‍♂️How did I miss this. Thank you, that was the solution.